# Are there any use of imaginary characteristics?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

For hyperbolic equations, characteristics tell how a signal propagates. For example, the equation $u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx} = 0$ has two characteristics $x\pm c t$. This means a signal propagates at speeds $\pm c$ starting from point $x$.

A similar, but elliptic equation $u_{tt} + c^2 u_{xx} = 0$ has two characteristics $x \pm i c t$. Now things are imaginary. But it must still mean something, right? For example, $u_{tt} + x^2 u_{xx} = 0$ is also elliptic but with two different characteristics. Can we extract some useful information of their (different) elliptic behavior, by looking at the imaginary characteristics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case the general solution is $$u=F(x-ct)+G(x+ct)$$ (method of characteristics)

In the second case the general solution is $$u=F(x-ict)+G(x+ict)$$ (method of complex variables). Sophisticated versions of this have been used to solve problems of transonic airflow.

Comment: I really have to ask, did you develop the Roe solver? Back to the question. To me changing $c$ to $i c $ in the general solution is a pure mathematical manipulation -- what's the physical insight? What does a signal speed $i c$ tell of the solution behavior? How it compares with a signal speed $i x$? My own experience is imaginary quantities are always hard to understand, but they bear lots of meaning once understood.

Comment: Guilty! What the imaginary characteristics tell you is that there are no real wavespeeds and no real characteristic lines, and no geomertric solutions. I doubt that there is any way to visualise this. So far, so negative, but if I say that there are no lines across which the solution can be discontinuous, no part of the boundary that does not influence a given point, things take a more positive turn. And if the form of the solution directs my attention to conformal transformations, then I'm on a winner

Comment: Such an honor! Thank you for your answer professor. Could you please point me some literature on the applications of complex characteristics to transonic airflow -- as you mentioned in your answer? I wish to see it in action.

Comment: The reference is Chan, C. K., and P. Garabedian. "Complex Analysis of Transonic Flow." Frontiers of Computational Fluid Dynamics (1998). You can access this online. The technique has never been widely adopted, because it is an inverse method and hard to make practical.